# Adding new lines to Alert text

Tags: apache-flex

I want to create a simple multiline Alert popup

```
Alert.show("Blah\\nBlah")
```

shows Blah\nBlah when what I really want is two lines, one Blah each.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it is anything like most languages, then you only need to have `\n` to get a new line. having `\\n` is saying that you actually do want to draw a `\` because normally the back slash is used to say you're about to do some thing special.

Comment: +1 beat me to it by 20 seconds. OP should use \n, not \\n for newline.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Alert.show("Blah\nBlah")
```